# How to group row values depending on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| K1 | 12 |
| K2 | 12 |
| S1 | 12 |
| K3 | 9 |
| K1 | 8 |
| K2 | 10 |

I want to make it so in this scenario, ONLY K1 and K2 are joined since, only in this specific point, the number 1 and 2 doesn't matter since the B column is matching. The letter is always important, so S1 cannot be joined.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| K | 12 |
| S1 | 12 |
| K3 | 9 |
| K1 | 8 |
| K2 | 10 |

It is also important that column A is not split.

So if K(1) = 12 = K(2) then join them to just make K, if that makes sense?
Is something like this possible?

The data given is premade so I can't change it whatsoever, unless there is a way to split that column and concatenate it back after the fix.

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL and *completely* different products. Which are you *really* using here? What is the difficulty you are having solving the problem? What about the articles/answers/documentation you read didn't you understand? What were your attempts? Why didn't they work? What are you expected results? What do you mean by the rows are "joined"?

Comment: Is that sample table and/or the expected result? We need both, a [mcve]. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @ThomA Sorry I am using sql server, the difficulty I'm having is that I don't know how to group two rows together with a specific clause. The articles I read either didn't have any comments at all, or were not related to what I wanted.

Comment: @ThomA I've added a table to what I want the outcome to be

Comment: Hi @jarlh, this is a sample table. I have added an expected result table as well. Since I am new with SQL, I haven't got a current query attempt as I don't really know what I'm doing :(

Comment: So does the row with `K` represent the highest value for a value with `K` at the start?

Comment: @ThomA There is K3 9, since, there are no other K(n), then there is no change. But because there are two values of K with the output 12 (K1 and K2), they are linked to just make K. It's annoying, but I didn't write any of this code, and it has to match this way in order for it to work elsewhere :/ They also cannot stay as K1 and K2, again, not my rules :/

Comment: So what would you expect if there was, say another row with `K2` `9`?

Comment: @ThomA The other values underneath K1 and K2 were just examples to show the only join I want. It's basically the same as me saying Apple1 has 12 pips, Apple2 has 12 pips, so in this batch we'll just say Apple has 12 pips

Comment: @ThomA if there was K2 9 and K3 9, I would just want K 9 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(A) > 1 THEN LEFT(A,1) ELSE MAX(A) END As A, B
FROM [table]
GROUP BY LEFT(A, 1), B
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/yiX1MnpX

Comment: Thank you, I know my wording has been terrible but this has definitely helped me understand more, thank you

Comment: Me again, is there any way I can specify column B if there is more than 1 other available column?

Comment: The other columns would (potentially) be grouped, so you need to know which value from the group to show.